# JPA Criteria builder How to group logical AND conditions

Tags: java, jpa

JPA Criteria builder How to group logical operator AND

Current

select * from Offers marketingo0_ where (upper(marketingo0_.SOURCE_KEY_UID)=? OR marketingo0_.STATUS=? and marketingo0_.STATUS=? )

Expected

select * from Offers marketingo0_ where upper(marketingo0_.SOURCE_KEY_UID)=? OR (marketingo0_.STATUS=? and marketingo0_.STATUS=? )

```
        List<Predicate> innerPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    List<Predicate> outerPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();


    //Create all outer predicates
    createPredicates(filter.getRootBooleanClause(),builder, marketingOffer, outerPredicates);


    //Create all sub clauses predicates
    for (BooleanClause subClause : filter.getRootBooleanClause().getSubClauses()) {

        List<Predicate> groupPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        createPredicates(subClause,builder, marketingOffer, groupPredicates);

        if(groupPredicates!=null && groupPredicates.size()>0 && filter.getOperator().equals(LogicOperator.OR)){
            innerPredicates.add(builder.and(groupPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[groupPredicates.size()])));
        }else if(groupPredicates!=null &&  groupPredicates.size()>0 && filter.getRootBooleanClause().getOperator().equals(LogicOperator.AND)){
            innerPredicates.add(builder.or(groupPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[groupPredicates.size()])));
        }
    }

    if(innerPredicates.size()>0){
        outerPredicates.addAll(innerPredicates);
    }


    if(outerPredicates.size()>0 && filter.getRootBooleanClause().getOperator().equals(LogicOperator.OR)){
        predicates.add(builder.or(outerPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[outerPredicates.size()])));
    }else if(outerPredicates.size()>0 && filter.getRootBooleanClause().getOperator().equals(LogicOperator.AND)){
        predicates.add(builder.and(outerPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[outerPredicates.size()])));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
builder.or(
    builder.and(
        <Column1 predicate>,
        <Column2 predicate>
    ),
    <ColumnC predicate>
);
```

The `CriteriaBuilder` will take care of correctly nesting the sub-expressions.

Comment: I have tried the you have mentioned, because i am getting and predicates and or predicates seperatly. it is not grouping the and condition.

Comment: In any case, `builder.and()` will return *a single* predicate which you can combine with any other predicate as desired.

Comment: If i combine, i am getting the output query something like this SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (COLUMN1="" OR COULUMN2='' AND COLUMN2='')

Comment: Then show us the exact statements you use to "combine" your predicates.

Comment: Please see the updated code now, i am trying to create the predicates dynamically.

Comment: Your code only shows how you create a *list* of predicates. But the important part is where and how you actually *combine* all the predicates from the list(s) into a single one for your query.

Comment: By the way: Is there any hierarchy/nesting possible in your `BooleanClause`? - Otherwise I don't see how this could be mapped consistently to nested sub-expressions.

Comment: The nesting is not determined, it has to build dynamically. A || (B & C), (A || B) & (C || D), A & B & (E || F) any thing is possible.

Comment: As I said: A mere *list* of predicates does *not* represent any nesting; so the question remains: How are all the predicates from the list combined in the end?

Comment: List<Predicate> predicates = composeFilterRestrictions(query, builder, filter, marketingOffer);
  query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

Comment: Hi Hanno, What is the purpose of disjunction function in criteria builder.

Comment: disjuction = or | conjunction = and

Comment: Ok, so the [`query.where(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#where%28javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...%29) should "and" all given predicates together. What's `predicates.size()` right before you add them to the query? Could it be it's only "1"?

Comment: I have found the solution, A || ( B & C), just adding criteriabuilder.disjunction().

Answer (score 1):

To achieve

```
upper(marketingo0_.SOURCE_KEY_UID)=? 
OR 
(marketingo0_.STATUS=? and marketingo0_.STATUS=? )
```

I think this should work

```
criteriaBuilder.or(
    criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.<String>get("SOURCE_KEY_UID")), key),
    criteriaBuilder.and(
        criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("STATUS"), status), 
        criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("STATUS"), status) // This doesnot make sense but sticking to OP
    )
)
```